# Footnotes in Google Docs

Tags: google-docs

I need to add some footnotes in a Google Doc page. I know how to add a single footnote (Insert=>Footnote), but I have the following problems

1) The inserted footnote size is 10. I need to change it to 8. It seems **impossible to change the automatic footnote font size**, should be added and then modified individually and manually.

2) I need to quote several new sources at once, (1)A, (2)B, (3)C and (4)D.

> This is my text<sup>[1-4]</sup>.

**Impossible to add <sup>`1-4`</sup>**, as the respective footnotes weren't yet added. All I can do is

> My text<sup>`[1,2,3,4]`</sup>

and this, only after adding four reference after "My text"<sup>`1234`</sup> one by one, then adding `[]` and `,` in superscript manually... (

---

Is it really impossible or there are ways to do it, however?

Comment: There is an add-on for styling footnote text [here](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/footnote-style/hlcpimnopaolddjgmgjeibnhgkgbnbai?hl=en)

Comment: thanks, @Alireid, the add-on partially resolves the point (1) - partially, because the font size is still not automatic, however, nothing to do with the point 2